# Generate Word Documents (in Excel VBA) from a series of Document Templates

Tags: excel, ms-word, documentation-generation, vba

Hey all. I'll try to make this brief and simple. :)

**I have**

1. 40 or so boilerplate word documents with a series of fields (Name, address, etc) that need to be filled in. This is historically done manually, but it's repetitive and cumbersome.
2. A workbook where a user has filled a huge set of information about an individual.

**I need**

- A way to programatically (from Excel VBA) open up these boilerplate documents, edit in the value of fields from various named ranges in the workbook, and save the filled in templates to a local folder.

If I were using VBA to programatically edit particular values in a set of spreadsheets, I would edit all those spreadsheets to contain a set of named ranges which could be used during the auto-fill process, but I'm not aware of any 'named field' feature in a Word document.

How could I edit the documents, and create a VBA routine, so that I can open each document, look for a set of fields which might need to be filled in, and substitute a value?

For instance, something that works like:

```
for each document in set_of_templates
    if document.FieldExists("Name") then document.Field("Name").value = strName
    if document.FieldExists("Address") then document.Field("Name").value = strAddress
    ...

    document.saveAs( thisWorkbook.Path & "\GeneratedDocs\ " & document.Name )
next document
```

Things I've considered:

- Mail merge - but this is insufficient because it requires opening each document manually and structuring the workbook as a data source, I kind of want the opposite. The templates are the data source and the workbook is iterating through them. Also, mail merge is for creating many identical documents using a table of different data. I have many documents all using the same data.
- Using placeholder text such as "#NAME#" and opening each document for a search and replace. This is the solution I would resort to if nothing more elegant is proposed.

Comment: Is there a reason that MailMerge does not suit?

Comment: Hey Remou, from the OP - I found the approach insufficient because it requires opening each document manually and structuring the workbook as a data source, I kind of want the opposite. The templates are the data source and the workbook is iterating through them. Also, mail merge is for creating many identical documents using a table of different data. I have many documents all using the same data.

Comment: Mailmerge can be run from VBA, that is, the data source can be set from VBA, and you can have any number of records. I reckon it would be much easier and take much less code than going through an indeterminate number of fields.

Comment: I think you may be looking at Mailmerge from the wrong direction. It works exactly like you want, that Excel holds the data to be filled into Word fields.

Comment: Mail-merge requires the existence of a Table in the selected excel document - a table which is configured to contain the data required to fill in the template word document. I have no such table, nor do I want to create one for each word document that needs to be filled out. I require a generic solution for substituting in certain parameters in a set of pre-configured documents. The workbook has no knowledge of the structure of the word documents and vice versa.

Comment: One way to do this is with bookmarks and code in a Word document and named ranges and code in Excel.  To do it right, get a copy of Professional Excel Development, which has a very good example that I've used more than once.  I tried searching the web just now but only got snippets, and PED is a great book if you're going to keep doing this kind of thing.

Comment: @Doug Glancy - I am doing this using named ranges and code in Excel, but I don't have the opportunity add code to the Word documents. There about 40 of them and they are meant to be plain rich-text templates, which will be changed from time to time by people who have no knowledge of this automation process. You mentioned bookmarks, and I'm curious about that, since I've never heard of them before. Is it similar to a named range in excel, where you can programatically refer to and modify a block of text using a variable name?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's been a long time since I asked this question, and my solution has undergone more and more refinement. I've had to deal with all sorts of special cases, such as values that come directly from the workbook, sections that need to be specially generated based on lists, and the need to do replacements in headers and footers.

As it turns out, it did not suffice to use bookmarks, as it was possible for users to later edit documents to change, add, and remove placeholder values from the documents. The solution was in fact to use **keywords** such as this:

[image]

This is just a page from a sample document which uses some of the possible values that can get automatically inserted into a document. Over 50 documents exist with completely different structures and layouts, and using different parameters. The only common knowledge shared by the word documents and the excel spreadsheet is a knowledge of what these placeholder values are meant to represent. In excel, this is stored in a list of document generation keywords, which contain the keyword, followed by a reference to the range that actually contains this value:

[image]

These were the key two ingredients required. Now with some clever code, all I had to do was iterate over each document to be generated, and then iterate over the range of all known keywords, and do a search and replace for each keyword in each document.

---

First, I have the wrapper method, which takes care of maintaining an instance of microsoft word iterating over all documents selected for generation, numbering the documents, and doing the user interface stuff (like handling errors, displaying the folder to the user, etc.)

```vb
' Purpose: Iterates over and generates all documents in the list of forms to generate
'          Improves speed by creating a persistant Word application used for all generated documents
Public Sub GeneratePolicy()
    Dim oWrd As New Word.Application
    Dim srcPath As String
    Dim cel As Range

    If ERROR_HANDLING Then On Error GoTo errmsg
    If Forms.Cells(2, FormsToGenerateCol) = vbNullString Then _
        Err.Raise 1, , "There are no forms selected for document generation."
    'Get the path of the document repository where the forms will be found.
    srcPath = FindConstant("Document Repository")
    'Each form generated will be numbered sequentially by calling a static counter function. This resets it.
    GetNextEndorsementNumber reset:=True
    'Iterate over each form, calling a function to replace the keywords and save a copy to the output folder
    For Each cel In Forms.Range(Forms.Cells(2, FormsToGenerateCol), Forms.Cells(1, FormsToGenerateCol).End(xlDown))
        RunReplacements cel.value, CreateDocGenPath(cel.Offset(0, 1).value), oWrd
    Next cel
    oWrd.Quit
    On Error Resume Next
    'Display the folder containing the generated documents
    Call Shell("explorer.exe " & CreateDocGenPath, vbNormalFocus)
    oWrd.Quit False
    Application.StatusBar = False
    If MsgBox("Policy generation complete. The reserving information will now be recorded.", vbOKCancel, _
              "Policy Generated. OK to store reserving info?") = vbOK Then Push_Reserving_Requirements
    Exit Sub
errmsg:
    MsgBox Err.Description, , "Error generating Policy Documents"
End Sub
```

That routine calls `RunReplacements` which takes care of opening the document, prepping the environment for a fast replacement, updating links once done, handling errors, etc:

```vb
' Purpose: Opens up a document and replaces all instances of special keywords with their respective values.
'          Creates an instance of Word if an existing one is not passed as a parameter.
'          Saves a document to the target path once the template has been filled in.
'
'          Replacements are done using two helper functions, one for doing simple keyword replacements,
'          and one for the more complex replacements like conditional statements and schedules.
Private Sub RunReplacements(ByVal DocumentPath As String, ByVal SaveAsPath As String, _
                            Optional ByRef oWrd As Word.Application = Nothing)
    Dim oDoc As Word.Document
    Dim oWrdGiven As Boolean
    If oWrd Is Nothing Then Set oWrd = New Word.Application Else oWrdGiven = True

    If ERROR_HANDLING Then On Error GoTo docGenError
    oWrd.Visible = False
    oWrd.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone

    Application.StatusBar = "Opening " & Mid(DocumentPath, InStrRev(DocumentPath, "\") + 1)
    Set oDoc = oWrd.Documents.Open(Filename:=DocumentPath, Visible:=False)
    RunAdvancedReplacements oDoc
    RunSimpleReplacements oDoc
    UpdateLinks oDoc 'Routine which will update calculated statements in Word (like current date)
    Application.StatusBar = "Saving " & Mid(DocumentPath, InStrRev(DocumentPath, "\") + 1)
    oDoc.SaveAs SaveAsPath

    GoTo Finally
docGenError:
    MsgBox "Un unknown error occurred while generating document: " & DocumentPath & vbNewLine _
            & vbNewLine & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Document Generation"
Finally:
    If Not oDoc Is Nothing Then oDoc.Close False: Set oDoc = Nothing
    If Not oWrdGiven Then oWrd.Quit False
End Sub
```

That routine then invokes `RunSimpleReplacements`. and `RunAdvancedReplacements`. In the former, we iterate over the set of Document Generation Keywords and call `WordDocReplace` if the document contains our keyword. Note that it's much faster to try and `Find` a bunch of words to figure out that they don't exist, then to call replace indiscriminately, so we always check if a keyword exists before attempting to replace it.

```vb
' Purpose: While short, this short module does most of the work with the help of the generation keywords
'          range on the lists sheet. It loops through every simple keyword that might appear in a document
'          and calls a function to have it replaced with the corresponding data from pricing.
Private Sub RunSimpleReplacements(ByRef oDoc As Word.Document)
    Dim DocGenKeys As Range, valueSrc As Range
    Dim value As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Set DocGenKeys = Lists.Range("DocumentGenerationKeywords")
    For i = 1 To DocGenKeys.Rows.Count
        If WordDocContains(oDoc, "#" & DocGenKeys.Cells(i, 1).Text & "#") Then
            'Find the text that we will be replacing the placeholder keyword with
            Set valueSrc = Range(Mid(DocGenKeys.Cells(i, 2).Formula, 2))
            If valueSrc.MergeCells Then value = valueSrc.MergeArea.Cells(1, 1).Text Else value = valueSrc.Text
            'Perform the replacement
            WordDocReplace oDoc, "#" & DocGenKeys.Cells(i, 1).Text & "#", value
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

This is the function used to detect whether a keyword exists in the document:

```vb
' Purpose: Function called for each replacement to first determine as quickly as possible whether
'          the document contains the keyword, and thus whether replacement actions must be taken.
Public Function WordDocContains(ByRef oDoc As Word.Document, ByVal searchFor As String) As Boolean
    Application.StatusBar = "Checking for keyword: " & searchFor
    WordDocContains = False
    Dim storyRange As Word.Range
    For Each storyRange In oDoc.StoryRanges
        With storyRange.Find
            .Text = searchFor
            WordDocContains = WordDocContains Or .Execute
        End With
        If WordDocContains Then Exit For
    Next
End Function
```

And this is where the rubber meets the road - the code that executes the replacement. This routine got more complicated as I encountered difficulties. Here are the lessons you will only learn from experience:

1. You can set the replacement text directly, or you can use the clipboard. I found out the hard way that if you are doing a VBA replace in word using a string longer than 255 characters, the text will get truncated if you try to place it in the `Find.Replacement.Text`, but you can use `"^c"` as your replacement text, and it will get it directly from the clipboard. This was the workaround I got to use.
2. Simply calling replace will miss keywords in some text areas like headers and footers. Because of this, you actually need to iterate over the `document.StoryRanges` and run the search and replace on each one to ensure that you catch all instances of the word you want to replace.
3. If you're setting the `Replacement.Text` directly, you need to convert Excel line breaks (`vbNewLine` and `Chr(10)`) with a simple `vbCr` for them to appear properly in word. Otherwise, anywhere your replacement text has line breaks coming from an excel cell will end up inserting strange symbols into word. If you use the clipboard method however, you do not need to do this, as the line breaks get converted automatically when put in the clipboard.

That explains everything. Comments should be pretty clear too. Here's the golden routine that executes the magic:

```vb
' Purpose: This function actually performs replacements using the Microsoft Word API
Public Sub WordDocReplace(ByRef oDoc As Word.Document, ByVal replaceMe As String, ByVal replaceWith As String)
    Dim clipBoard As New MSForms.DataObject
    Dim storyRange As Word.Range
    Dim tooLong As Boolean

    Application.StatusBar = "Replacing instances of keyword: " & replaceMe

    'We want to use regular search and replace if we can. It's faster and preserves the formatting that
    'the keyword being replaced held (like bold).  If the string is longer than 255 chars though, the
    'standard replace method doesn't work, and so we must use the clipboard method (^c special character),
    'which does not preserve formatting. This is alright for schedules though, which are always plain text.
    If Len(replaceWith) > 255 Then tooLong = True
    If tooLong Then
        clipBoard.SetText IIf(replaceWith = vbNullString, "", replaceWith)
        clipBoard.PutInClipboard
    Else
        'Convert excel in-cell line breaks to word line breaks. (Not necessary if using clipboard)
        replaceWith = Replace(replaceWith, vbNewLine, vbCr)
        replaceWith = Replace(replaceWith, Chr(10), vbCr)
    End If
    'Replacement must be done on multiple 'StoryRanges'. Unfortunately, simply calling replace will miss
    'keywords in some text areas like headers and footers.
    For Each storyRange In oDoc.StoryRanges
        Do
            With storyRange.Find
                .MatchWildcards = True
                .Text = replaceMe
                .Replacement.Text = IIf(tooLong, "^c", replaceWith)
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            End With
            On Error Resume Next
            Set storyRange = storyRange.NextStoryRange
            On Error GoTo 0
        Loop While Not storyRange Is Nothing
    Next
    If tooLong Then clipBoard.SetText ""
    If tooLong Then clipBoard.PutInClipboard
End Sub
```

When the dust settles, we're left with a beautiful version of the initial document with production values in place of those hash marked keywords. I'd love to show an example, but of course every filled in document contain all-proprietary information.

---

The only think left to mention I guess would be that `RunAdvancedReplacements` section. It does something extremely similar - it ends up calling the same `WordDocReplace` function, but what's special about the keywords used here is that they don't link to a single cell in the original workbook, they get generated in the code-behind from lists in the workbook. So for instance, one of the advanced replacements would look like this:

```vb
'Generate the schedule of vessels
If WordDocContains(oDoc, "#VESSELSCHEDULE#") Then _
    WordDocReplace oDoc, "#VESSELSCHEDULE#", GenerateVesselSchedule()
```

And then there will be a corresponding routine which puts together a string containing all the vessel information as configured by the user:

```vb
' Purpose: Generates the list of vessels from the "Vessels" sheet based on the user's configuration
'          in the booking tab. The user has the option to generate one or both of Owned Vessels
'          and Chartered Vessels, as well as what fields to display. Uses a helper function.
Public Function GenerateVesselSchedule() As String
    Dim value As String

    Application.StatusBar = "Generating Schedule of Vessels."
    If Booking.Range("ListVessels").value = "Yes" Then
        Dim VesselCount As Long

        If Booking.Range("ListVessels").Offset(1).value = "Yes" Then _
            value = value & GenerateVesselScheduleHelper("Vessels", VesselCount)
        If Booking.Range("ListVessels").Offset(1).value = "Yes" And _
           Booking.Range("ListVessels").Offset(2).value = "Yes" Then _
            value = value & "(Chartered Vessels)" & vbNewLine
        If Booking.Range("ListVessels").Offset(2).value = "Yes" Then _
            value = value & GenerateVesselScheduleHelper("CharteredVessels", VesselCount)
        If Len(value) > 2 Then value = Left(value, Len(value) - 2) 'Remove the trailing line break
    Else
        GenerateVesselSchedule = Booking.Range("VesselSchedAlternateText").Text
    End If
    GenerateVesselSchedule = value
End Function

' Purpose: Helper function for the Vessel Schedule generation routine. Generates either the Owned or
'          Chartered vessels based on the schedule parameter passed. The list is numbered and contains
'          the information selected by the user on the Booking sheet.
' SENSITIVE: Note that this routine is sensitive to the layout of the Vessel Schedule tab and the
'            parameters on the Configure Quotes tab. If either changes, it should be revisited.
Public Function GenerateVesselScheduleHelper(ByVal schedule As String, ByRef VesselCount As Long) As String
    Dim value As String, nextline As String
    Dim numInfo As Long, iRow As Long, iCol As Long
    Dim Inclusions() As Boolean, Columns() As Long

    'Gather info about vessel info to display in the schedule
    With Booking.Range("VesselInfoToInclude")
        numInfo = Booking.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .End(xlToRight)).Columns.Count - 1
        ReDim Inclusions(1 To numInfo)
        ReDim Columns(1 To numInfo)
        On Error Resume Next 'Some columns won't be identified
        For iCol = 1 To numInfo
            Inclusions(iCol) = .Offset(0, iCol) = "Yes"
            Columns(iCol) = sumSchedVessels.Range(schedule).Cells(1).EntireRow.Find(.Offset(-1, iCol)).Column
        Next iCol
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Build the schedule
    With sumSchedVessels.Range(schedule)
        For iRow = .row + 1 To .row + .Rows.Count - 1
            If Len(sumSchedVessels.Cells(iRow, Columns(1)).value) > 0 Then
                VesselCount = VesselCount + 1
                value = value & VesselCount & "." & vbTab
                nextline = vbNullString
                'Add each property that was included to the description string
                If Inclusions(1) Then nextline = nextline & sumSchedVessels.Cells(iRow, Columns(1)) & vbTab
                If Inclusions(2) Then nextline = nextline & "Built: " & sumSchedVessels.Cells(iRow, Columns(2)) & vbTab
                If Inclusions(3) Then nextline = nextline & "Length: " & _
                                      Format(sumSchedVessels.Cells(iRow, Columns(3)), "#'") & vbTab
                If Inclusions(4) Then nextline = nextline & "" & sumSchedVessels.Cells(iRow, Columns(4)) & vbTab
                If Inclusions(5) Then nextline = nextline & "Hull Value: " & _
                                      Format(sumSchedVessels.Cells(iRow, Columns(5)), "$#,##0") & vbTab
                If Inclusions(6) Then nextline = nextline & "IV: " & _
                                      Format(sumSchedVessels.Cells(iRow, Columns(6)), "$#,##0") & vbTab
                If Inclusions(7) Then nextline = nextline & "TIV: " & _
                                      Format(sumSchedVessels.Cells(iRow, Columns(7)), "$#,##0") & vbTab
                If Inclusions(8) And schedule = "CharteredVessels" Then _
                    nextline = nextline & "Deductible: " & Format(bmCharterers.Range(schedule).Cells( _
                               iRow - .row, 9), "$#,##0") & vbTab
                nextline = Left(nextline, Len(nextline) - 1) 'Remove the trailing tab
                'If more than 4 properties were included insert a new line after the 4th one
                Dim tabloc As Long: tabloc = 0
                Dim counter As Long: counter = 0
                Do
                    tabloc = tabloc + 1
                    tabloc = InStr(tabloc, nextline, vbTab)
                    If tabloc > 0 Then counter = counter + 1
                Loop While tabloc > 0 And counter < 4
                If counter = 4 Then nextline = Left(nextline, tabloc - 1) & vbNewLine & Mid(nextline, tabloc)
                value = value & nextline & vbNewLine
            End If
        Next iRow
    End With

    GenerateVesselScheduleHelper = value
End Function
```

the resulting string can be used just like the contents of any excel cell, and passed to the replacement function, which will appropriately use the clipboard method if it exceeds 255 characters.

**So this template:**

[image]

**Plus this spreadsheet data:**

[image]

**Becomes this document:**

[image]

---

I sincerely hope that this helps someone out some day. It was definitely a huge undertaking and a complex wheel to have to re-invent. The application is huge, with over 50,000 lines of VBA code, so if I've referenced a crucial method in my code somewhere that someone needs, please leave a comment and I'll add it in here.

Comment: This is fantastic!  I can't describe how happy I am that you posted this answer in such detail.

Comment: well done for an exceptional answer, though where I work we built an application that does this for hundreds of letters daily in vb.net taking the data from SQL Server...

Comment: in our .NET version, we use `{` and `}` as placeholders around fields that will be replaced...

Answer (score 3):

http://www.computorcompanion.com/LPMArticle.asp?ID=224 Describes the use of Word **bookmarks**

A section of text in a document can be *bookmarked*, and given a variable name. Using VBA, this variable can be accessed and the content in the document can be replaced with alternate content. This is a solution to having placeholders such as Name and Address in the document.

Furthermore, using bookmarks, documents can be modified to reference bookmarked text. If a name appears several times throughout a document, the first instance can be bookmarked, and additional instances can reference the bookmark. Now when the first instance is programatically changed, all other instances of the variable throughout the document are also automatically changed.

Now all that's needed is to update all the documents by bookmarking the placeholder text and using a consistent naming convention throughout the documents, then iterate through each documents replacing the bookmark if it exists:

```
document.Bookmarks("myBookmark").Range.Text = "Inserted Text"
```

I can probably solve the problem of variables that don't appear in a given document using the on error resume next clause before attempting each replacement.

Thanks to [Doug Glancy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/293078/doug-glancy) for mentioning the existance of bookmarks in his comment. I had no knowledge of their existence beforehand. I will keep this topic posted on whether this solution suffices.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider an XML based approach.

Word has a feature called Custom XML data-binding, or data-bound content controls.  A content control is essentially a point in the document which can contain content. A "data-bound" content control gets its content from an XML document you include in the docx zip file.  An XPath expression is used to say which bit of XML.  So all you need to do is include your XML file, and Word will do the rest.

Excel has ways to get data out of it as XML, so the whole solution should work nicely.

There is plenty of information on content control data-binding on MSDN (some of which has been referenced in earlier SO questions) so I won't bother including them here.

But you do need a way of setting up the bindings.  You can either use the Content Control Toolkit, or if you want to do it from within Word, my OpenDoPE add-in.

Comment: This would be really neat approach because it doesn't require opening the word file or using office interop to chance the contents. I'll do some research in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

Having done a similar task I found that inserting values into tables was much quicker than searching for named tags - the data can then be inserted like this:

```
    With oDoc.Tables(5)
    For i = 0 To Data.InvoiceDictionary.Count - 1
        If i > 0 Then
            oDoc.Tables(5).rows.Add
        End If
         Set invoice = Data.InvoiceDictionary.Items(i)
        .Cell(i + 2, 1).Range.Text = invoice.InvoiceCCNumber
        .Cell(i + 2, 2).Range.Text = invoice.InvoiceDate
        .Cell(i + 2, 3).Range.Text = invoice.TransactionType
        .Cell(i + 2, 4).Range.Text = invoice.Description
        .Cell(i + 2, 5).Range.Text = invoice.SumOfValue

    Next i
```

.Cell(i + 1, 4).Range.Text = "Total:"
    End With
in this case row 1 of the table was the headers; row 2 was empty and there were no further rows - thus the rows.add applies once more than one row was attached.  The tables can be very detailed documents and by hiding the borders and cell borders can be made to look like ordinary text. Tables are numbered sequentially following the document flow.  (i.e. Doc.Tables(1) is the first table...