# Copy data from Excel to Word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a .csv file which I can export and from which I need to copy data into word.
I know how to get the relevant data from Excel and format my .csv file with VBA, however I don't know how to get my data from that Excel file to Word.

Basically this is how a line of my formatted .csv file looks (I Got rid of all the info I don't need).

[image: CSV formatted output]

For clarification: 1st long nr. is personnel 2nd one is token.

And I need to fill that info into the following table in word (Not everything gets filled in).

[image: Word Table]

And one extra thing, depending on the extention of the email address @mc or @lmc, I need a different file opened (Different languages). How would I best do that?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106743/generate-word-documents-in-excel-vba-from-a-series-of-document-templates

Answer (score 0):

Possible algorithm:

In your Excel document, develop a VBA macro that

Copy data/elements from Excel document

Open your word document

Paste excel data to word document (to the places you want)

Save word document

Close word document

[Here](http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/5/22/copy-paste-an-excel-table-into-microsoft-word-with-vba) is some code for inspiration of how to do that.