# Generating documents by template using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, documentation

I am currently working on a project, that consists generating various document examples in a new workbook, basing on the table data and document template. Here's what I have tried:

```
Sub CopyData()
    Sheets("Staff").Select

    For i = 2 To 100000
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then
            i = 100000
            Exit For
        End If

        Sheets("TEMPLATE_TARGET").Select

        Range("Name").Value = Sheets("Staff").Cells(i, 1).Value & " " & _
        Range("Personalcode").Value = Sheets("Staff").Cells(i, 3).Value
        Range("Residence").Value = Sheets("Staff").Cells(i, 4).Value
        Range("Job").Value = Sheets("Staff").Cells(i, 5).Value
        Cells.copy
        Selection.Copy

        Worksheets.Add.Name = Sheets("Staff").Cells(i, 1).Value

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        Sheets("Staff").Select
    Next i

    MsgBox ("YAY")
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, my code's executing stops in the middle of process, claiming that the worksheet("Staff") is already existing and therefore - is out of range. How do you recommend to indicate the option to generate the final results as the new workbook to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error message? On which line do you get it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate Word Documents (in Excel VBA) from a series of Document Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106743/generate-word-documents-in-excel-vba-from-a-series-of-document-templates)

Comment: @jūlija-Žarnauska: have a look at [Generate Word Documents (in Excel VBA) from a series of Document Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106743/generate-word-documents-in-excel-vba-from-a-series-of-document-templates)

Comment: I've got the run-time error message 1004 on the property: Worksheets.Add.Name=Sheets("Staff") and I'm afraid that renaming the sheet isn't the proper solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Declare a variable `As Worksheet` and then set it to the add method.

```
Dim oWorkSheet As worksheet

Set oWorkSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(, , 1, xlWorksheet)
oWorkSheet.Name = "nameOfYourSheet" 'must be different from the others sheets.
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
Worksheets.Add.Name = Sheets("Staff").Cells(i, 1).Value
```

with

```
With Worksheets.Add
    .Name = Sheets("Staff").Cells(i, 1).Value
End With
```